# match 32-byte hash value with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed, hash

I'd like to extract hash values with `sed` from strings like this one:

`[129.173.213.225:52196] some_text: another_text --> eb1d94daa7e0344597e756a1fb6e7054`

The desired result is just have the 32-byte hash value, eb1d94daa7e0344597e756a1fb6e7054 in this example.

So I tried the following command with `regexp` (idea is to remove all except the matched pattern):

```
% sed 's/\([0-9a-f]{32}\)$/\1/g' < file
```

which results in error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Passing `-r` to sed didn't help, I'm getting the same error.

I think the regexp itself is correct because  `sed -r 's/[0-9a-f]{32}$/XXX/g'` does replace the 32-byte hash value with XXX string. But I want to remove *all* of the string except the hash value.

```
% cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS \n \l

%
% ls -la `which sed`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 73424 Feb 11  2016 /bin/sed
%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: even though the command wouldn't work, `sed 's/\([0-9a-f]{32}\)$/\1/g'` should not result in an error unless you have `sed` aliased to `sed -r` or `sed -E`... for default BRE, you need to use `\{\}` for quantifiers.. with ERE, both `()` and `{}` will work as metacharacters

Comment: for your problem, I'd rather use `grep -o '[0-9a-f]\{32\}$'` instead of sed

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks for feedback. Command `sed 's/\([0-9a-f]{32}\)$/\1/g'` didn't work for me, i.e. it doesn't fail but doesn't extract hash value, it prints the original line.

Comment: when you do `echo 'foo and bar' | sed 's/and/1/'`, only `and` is replaced and rest of the line remains as is.. so, if you want to remove all characters before the hex value, you need to tell sed to match them... `sed 's/.*\([0-9a-f]\{32\}\)$/\1/'` (also note the use of `\{\}` and that `g` is not needed as this can only match once)

Comment: @Sundeep, I see -- so we match on the whole input line, _but_ exclude part of the expression using "(" and ")" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to substitute everything up to the `-->` part of the line with an empty string:
i.e. substitute what matches `.* -->`.

So the command would be:

```
sed 's/.* -->//g' < file
```

Even if `some_text` contains the arrow symbol, we are using the [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) regex, which will match as long as it can.

The result of the example line follows:

```
«~» $ sed 's/.* -->//g' < testregex 
 eb1d94daa7e0344597e756a1fb6e7054
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this as well

```
awk '/-->/ {print $NF}' file
```

It will find lines with `-->` then print last field.